# Java query to solve

Tags: java, eclipse

This is the question:

> Given a circle with the declaration double centerX=0, centerY=0, take
>   radius and a point with coordinates x, y. Write a program that
>   computes whether or not the point lies inside the circle (including
>   the boundary).
>
> Formula:
>
> The distance between two points A (x1,y1) and B(x2,y2) is:
>
> the square root of ((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2)
>
> Input Specification :
>
> The first line will contain the radius r.
>
> Second line contains x and y. Each value will be the (x,y) coordinate
>   such that x, y>0.
>
> Output Specification :
>
> If point lies within the circle print "The point (x, y) is inside the
>   circle", else print "The point (x, y) is outside the circle".
>
> Sample input 1:
>
> 7
>
> 2 5
>
> Sample output 1:
>
> The point (2, 5) is inside the circle
>
> Sample input 2:
>
> 2
>
> 9 4
>
> Sample output 2:
>
> The point (9, 4) is outside the circle
>
> Explanation:
>
> In Sample input 1, the distance between (0,0) and (2,5) is 5.3851
>   which is less than the radius 7. Hence the point is inside the circle.
>   Whereas in the other set of input, the point is outside the circle
>   because the distance between origin and (9,4) is 9.8488 which is
>   greater than the given radius 2.

Now this is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.*;
class Circ{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
        int r=s.nextInt();
        int x=s.nextInt();
        int y=s.nextInt();
        if(x>0&&y>0){
            double dist=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x-0,2)+Math.pow(y-0,2));
        if(dist>r){
            System.out.println("The point ("+x+","+y+") is outside the circle");
        }else if(dist<=r){
            System.out.println("The point ("+x+","+y+") is inside the circle");
        }
        }

    }
}
```

It is giving the right output but not passing the test cases ?

[image]

Comment: `JavaScript` and `Java` aren't quite the same. Please remove the `JavaScript` tag.

Comment: Do you know what the test cases are?

Comment: It is given in the question @marstran

Comment: Post the test cases input value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class circleOfCodeG{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int  r,x,y;
    double dis;
    r=sc.nextInt();
    x=sc.nextInt(); y=sc.nextInt();
    dis=Math.sqrt((x*x)+(y*y));
    if(dis<=r)
        System.out.println("The point ("+x+", "+y+") is inside the circle");
    else
        System.out.println("The point ("+x+", "+y+") is outside the circle");
}
}
```

Try this one. I'm sure, this'll fulfill "the test cases". :)